# Android Fragments - How to implement Backstacking and Recalling previous fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have android screen layout shown below

[image]

Apps screen divided into 3 fragments, Header, Footer and Content.  Header and Footer fragments are fixed.  Content fragment is changing according to content.  I replaces fragment1-fragment3 according to need.  Initially Fragment1 is shows in content area.  When i press a next button fragment1 is replace by fragment2.  This is the order.  I have question, if i press another button previous, how can  i return to previous fragment ( fragment2 -> fragment1).   Is any built in mechanism available in fragment class.

Please guide me...

thanks in advance

Comment: use addToBackStack() function of FragmentTransaction. [Details here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#addToBackStack%28java.lang.String%29)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you try to call new fragment then add back stack for it through

```
 ft.addToBackStack(null);
```

And now if you want to back from one fragment to another then, make one method..

```
public void DeleteCurrentFragment()
{
 FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

 Fragment currentFrag =  getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.detailFragment);


 String fragName = "NONE";

 if (currentFrag!=null)
    fragName = currentFrag.getClass().getSimpleName();


 if (currentFrag != null)
    transaction.remove(currentFrag);

 transaction.commit();

 }
```

And after that call this:

```
 getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
 DeleteCurrentFragment();
```

Comment: OK worked... Another doubt, My initial Fragement is fragment1, if i call above code (ie getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
 DeleteCurrentFragment();) it goes blank.  How can i find i was in first fragment.

Comment: for that you can use findFragmentByTag() method in which may be you can find easily with tag which you given a fragment when you are initializing it........

Comment: Is any count is available for backstack.  It is easy if count is zero then stop popBackStack.

Comment: No...you have to identify by string something like findFragmentByTag("tag") or ft.addToBackStack("tag");

Answer (score 2):

try this code

```
FragmentTransaction tx = fragmentManager.beginTransation();
tx.replace( R.id.fragment, new MyFragment() ).addToBackStack( "tag" ).commit();
```

Comment: OK.  How can i show previous fragment.  Please give more info

Comment: The above handles phone back button by default. If you want to handle back button on your own, i prefer maintaining backstack ourselves such that we can do according to our requirements

Comment: If you want any sample, let me know

Comment: Yes.  If i press back button of phone/tab in the fragment it exit to home

Answer (score 1):

you can try something like:

```
FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
ft.add(R.id.contentFragment, <your fragment>);
ft.addToBackStack(null);
ft.commit();
```

so suppose you're on `fragment1` and after doing some stuff you want push `fragment2` then on your `contentFragment` you can `add` or `replace` the fragment (`fragment2` in this case) as per your requirement. Now when you call `addToBackStack` it means add this transaction to the back stack. So that the transaction will be remembered after it is committed, and will reverse its operation when later popped off the stack. Internally it maintains a stack so you don't want to do anything. At last when you press back button from `fragment2` it checks whether the transaction having any fragment in its stack, if yes then it calls it. Its like top of stack. When you call `addToBackStack` in that stack fragment1 is added. So when you press back button stack's top is `fragment1` so it calls it.

It happens when you press **hardware back button**. If you want to do this on any button, then on that button's click listener simply `onBackPressed()` method.

Comment: Nice... how can show/callback previous fragment if i press a previous button

Comment: OK. If i press previous button how can i remove current fragment.

Comment: you don't have to remove anything if you're on fragment2, that will be handled internally.